# I cannot execute rake db:migrate - Unexpected ':'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, web-applications, rake

I am taking an online web for app design. I'm working with ubuntu for ruby on rails installation. I've tried running these commands:

```
rails new hello_WWW
cd hello_www
rails generate scaffold pioneer first_name:string last_name:string
```

Everything works okay. Next, I run `rake db:migrate`. However, I get this error message:

```
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:37: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:110: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /root/hello_WWW/db/migrate/20200413005922_create_pioneers.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected ':'
      t.string : first_name
               ^

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with —trace)
```

Can someone please help me resolve these issues?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a syntax error into the file `db/migrate/20200413005922_create_pioneers.rb`

```
t.string : first_name
```

should be

```
t.string :first_name
```